# jquery ui sortable - pass additional data to the script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am sorting a table like so which works fine:

```
var someVar = 'some var';
// do ajax on sortable
     $('table#pages tbody').sortable({
        items: "tr:not(.first)",
        update: function() {
            var ids = $('table#pages tbody').sortable('serialize');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: site + "pages/reorder_pages",
                data: ids,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.results').html(data);
                }
            });
            // $('.results').text('processing');   
        }

    });
```

But I also want to pass the `someVar` variable with the `data` parameter, not just `ids`, how can I do that? Wrapping all data parameters in an object does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this option possible:

```
url: site + "pages/reorder_pages?someVar=" + someVar
```

there are many others but that is particularly simple.

Comment: What are some other options?  Ideally I'd like to add additional data attributes.